# Why does string size not change if I add an additional character in it?

Tags: c++, string, c++11

In the below program, when I add one more character to string, its size still remains the same (as evident from str1.size() function). Why is that?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {

        std::string str1 = "hello";
        cout << "std::string str1 = \"hello\""<< endl;

        cout << "string is " << str1 << " with length " << str1.size() << endl;

        str1[5] = 'a';


        cout << "string is " << str1 << " with length " << str1.size() << endl;

   for (int i = 0 ; i < 7; i++) {
                cout << "str["<<i<<"] = " << str1[i] << " (int)(str[i])" << (int)str1[i] << endl;
        }
}
```

Output

```
std::string str1 = "hello"
string is hello with length 5
string is hello with length 5 //expected 6
str[0] = h (int)(str[i])104
str[1] = e (int)(str[i])101
str[2] = l (int)(str[i])108
str[3] = l (int)(str[i])108
str[4] = o (int)(str[i])111
str[5] = a (int)(str[i])97
str[6] =  (int)(str[i])0
```

Comment: *when I add one more character to string* -- Where are you doing that?  There is no "adding a character" in your program.

Comment: This misunderstanding is exactly why people teaching C++ should NOT begin with C. Starting with `int`, `std::string` and `std::vector` teaches C++ and gets things done. How a vector or string actually looks like and how to use the C things in C++ are interesting, but more advanced. `std::vector<std::string> args(argv + 1, argv + argc);` should be one of the first taught statements so exercises can include basic argument handling.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Operaton `str1[5] = 'a';` does not "add" something to a string; it sets the value at a particular position, and the position must be in the range `0..(length()-1)`; Otherwise, the behaviour is undefined.

To append something to a string, use

```
str1 += "a";
```

or

```
str1.push_back('a');
```

Note that an `std::string` - in contrast to plain "C"-style strings - maintains the `length` in a separate property (and does not calculate it purely relying on  a string terminating character `'\0'`).

Comment: How does the size() function figure out the length of string (here we see that it is not NULL terminated, after I do `str1[5] = 'a';`)

Comment: It would be worth pointing out that assigning a value to `str1[5]` when the string's value is "hello" (and its length is 5)  then is undefined behavior. The trailing 0 is not guaranteed to be stored in the character array holding the actual string characters so that a write to index 5 is out of bounds. If you use `at()` instead of `operator[]` the string should throw an exception.